# Updating AR associations through _id attributes doesn't update associated object (before validation)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, associations, updating

Let's say I have two ActiveRecord models: LineItem and Article.

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
  ...
end
```

I'm experiencing the following behaviour on LineItems (Rails 2.3.11):

```
>> l = LineItem.new
=> #<LineItem id: nil, article_id: nil, ...>
>> l.article_id=10
=> 10
>> l.article
=> #<Article id: 10, ...>
>> l.article_id=20
=> 20
>> l.article
=> #<Article id: 10, ...>
```

So if article_id already has a value, a subsequent change doesn't change the article association anymore. (At least not immediately - only after save it has been set to the new value.)

This is causing me problems in my validate method when updating existing LineItems. In my LineItems-Controller I do update like this:

```
def update
  @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
  @line_item.attributes = params[:data] #params[:data] contains article_id
  ...      
  @line_item.save!
  ...
end
```

In my LineItem class I have many validations like this (simplified):

```
def validate
  if self.article.max_size < self.size
    errors.add_to_base("Too big for chosen article.")
  end
end
```

On updates this validation acts on the 'old' article since the new one is only in self.article_id (but not in self.article) at this point. I could replace `self.article` with `Article.find(self.article_id)` in the condition above but this doesn't look like the way it's meant to be.

Is this a bug in rails (2.3.11) or am I doing something wrong? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a bug you are encountering, but rather the behaviour of the AR association cache. You can force the association to be reloaded during validation by passing `true` to the associtaion method: `self.article(true)`.

You could also clear all cached assocations for a LineItem instance by calling `#clear_association_cache`.

UPDATE:

It actually was a bug, but it has been fixed! (See Alex's comment)

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick. Remarks: While passing true to the association always works, `self.clear_association_cache` doesn't work in the irb example above because it doesn't act on new (unsaved) records. But using it in a before_validation callback should usually be fine.

Comment: This actually is a bug, a pretty horrible one that wreaks all kinds of havoc around the internet. It's fixed in 3.1 or 3.2, but I run into it frequently with 3.0 and some earlier versions. If an association is referenced prior to the _id changing (not uncommon in model filters) the the association is not changed.